# implement Leaflet Control OSM Geocoder in laravel/angular

Tags: angularjs, laravel, leaflet, geocode

I have succesfull implemented leaflet (bower package) and OSM Geocoder (https://github.com/k4r573n/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder) in my Laravel application.

Laravel is controlled through angular, but the OSM Geocoder is just added in another javascript file.

Can I implement the OSM Geocoder code through angular?
Or if this is not possible, how do I acces variables and functions from outside angular inside of my angular controller?

But, I have read this is not a good solution (it's not angular-way)?

How should I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck just as you were trying to implement a [different geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder).

For you the following should work (assuming you have already gotten the map itself to work):

```
function MyController($scope, leafletData) {
    leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
        var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.OSMGeocoder();
        osmGeocoder.addTo(map);
    });
}
```